# How to make animation in CSS with one large paragraph the size of main div with line breaks

Tags: html, css

```css
.main {
  width: 400px;
}

p.slide-out {
  padding: 1em;
  line-break: strict;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* Ensures the content is not revealed until the animation */
  border-right: .15em solid orange;
  /* The typwriter cursor */
  white-space: pre;
  /* this is important */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* Gives that scrolling effect as the typing happens */
  letter-spacing: .15em;
  /* Adjust as needed */
  animation: typing 3.5s steps(40, end), blink-caret .75s step-end infinite;
}


/* The typing effect */

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}


/* The typewriter cursor effect */

@keyframes blink-caret {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <p class="slide-out">In a future version of jsonlite, this option will not be supported, and named vectors will be translated into arrays instead of objects. If you want JSON object output, please use a named list instead.</p>
</div>
```

The idea is to "fit" the paragraph content inside the `.main` div. As the paragraph grows the lines are breaking. But, somehow, it is not working.  Any help?

Comment: if the main div is a fixed width then I think you would have to split your p into lines and wrap the lines in spans and put the animations on those - here's a quick example: https://jsfiddle.net/aobsrz1g/1/

Comment: @Pete thanks for your time! I will try it. But the problem is that my paragraph is huge and  its hard to split it.

Comment: If you do a search for "multi line typing cursor animation" there are quite a few options you can use - for example [this one](https://dev.to/afif/a-multi-line-css-only-typewriter-effect-3op3), but you would need to know the number of characters and use a monospaced font type

Comment: @Pete thanks for your time again! Amazing link that you sent me! have a good day!